# Transparent PNG on top of texture background

Tags: css, png, transparency

I have a problem with a transparent PNG (gradient), when placing the image on top of a textured background, the PNG gets filled with a white semi transparent color, and I can't figure out why.

I need it to just be transparent.

See on top of this photo.
http://i48.tinypic.com/33o71vt.jpg

Below is the css/less:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

#bgWrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:     100%;
background-image:url('/media/images/site/FrontpageTopBg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#homepage {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 970px;
}

#teaser{
    float: left;
    height: 343px;
}
```

Comment: Provide a link to your PNG please. Odds are that it has a slightly white background itself that you don't notice in your image editor.

Comment: A Fiddle would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the white Background layer in Photoshop when you made your png?

Comment: Ive updated the background to a png 24-bit image.

The transparent image that not completely transparent:
http://i45.tinypic.com/zyc5yt.png

The background texture:
http://i46.tinypic.com/28by3c3.png

Comment: estrar: Completely sure. I save it for web, png 24-bit, and there's no background color.

Comment: When I look at it in PS I see that it has a white, transparent background.

Comment: See this link: http://s9.postimage.org/cr44c4arz/zyc5yt.png - I added a red background layer underneath your png and erased a little bit of it. See the problem? You have to make a new PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Your png has a semi-transparent white background layer underneath it (open it with an image editor and add a red background layer under the png - the red background will become brighter).

You need to make a new png from scratch and make sure there are no semi-transparent backgrounds.

[image: Your not so transparent png]

Answer (score 0):

Open your PNG image in some image editor/viewer, eg XnView, and read the pixel value near the bottom, in the center. I get a value of `R=255 G=255 B=255 A=128`, which means "White, 50% transparent". Hence, it's not fully transparent, and the behaviour you see is the expected one.